# Completely Rewrite a Bad Question or Create a New One

Tags: discussion

If I create a question that is so terrible in every possible way, should I be completely rewriting it into a new, better question that makes more sense with my new knowledge and ideas on how to overcome it, or should I just leave it alone and start a new question?

Comment: And if you really would like here's the question that got me thinking of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576396/php-check-for-certain-words-to-create-dictionary-link
I am not sure what to do about it. It was terrible from the start, and it's still terrible.

Comment: "So terrible in every possible way?" I'll level with you:  even though it's tagged with [tag:php], you're at least *trying* to improve it...

Comment: @Makato Yes I have tried, but even reading back on it, even I can clearly see why people complained about it so much and why it was considered such a bad question...

Comment: @PaulCrovella That is why I was wondering if I should just pretty much completely rewrite it or start a new one. If I were to make a new one, it wouldn't start out with bad reputation and would be considered "new" by StackOverflow, however then I don't exactly know what to do with the old one...

Comment: @Paul Crovella Well unsurprisingly, I was banned from posting questions due to my terrible question, so I'll just edit it and try to do other things to get unbanned. Thanks for your suggestion. I really appreciate everybody's help and support on this website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is so bad that your rewrite would make it look like a totally different question, I'd delete it and start again.

If it already had answers, I'd think twice but only if they were good answers (in which case the question may not be as bad as you think). One thing you shouldn't do is change the question in such a way that it invalidates answers to date. If it does that, it's almost certainly a *different* question.

Since your linked question had no answers, I'd definitely delete and start over.

And remember when you're asking a question, think what info you would need were you to answer it yourself. Then try to supply that up front.

Answer (score 0):

That question is terrible because the people/programmers here won't suggest you some code. We will help you with the problem you are facing in your code or the code you have getting from somewhere and are trying to implement. And another issue is as the comments suggest you have presented a very broad view of the scenario you are facing. Please be specific about the problem and narrow down you approach.

And as per your question it's your choice you can start a new one or improve/edit this question also. If the question is as per standards of this site it will get upvoted eventually. 
Also go through these links so that you get the idea how to post an ideal question on stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Hope it helps. !!!

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at that and see. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, we *do* suggest code, on the right kind of questions. Consider for example that algorithm-questions are on-topic...